# navigator.app.exitapp() not working in android device

Tags: android, cordova

```
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
  function onDeviceReady() {
  document.addEventListener("backbutton", backButtonEvent, false);
}
   function backButtonEvent() {
    var currentUrl=window.location.hash;
     if(currentUrl=='#/homePage' || currentUrl=='#/'){
navigator.app.exitApp();
 }
else{
  history.go(-1);
  navigator.app.backhistory();
  }
}
```

Iam using ionic framework and phone gap.. here when i click device backbutton from home page its just minimizing that app not exiting. How can i exit my app??

Comment: exiting means killing the App process ? or just exiting out of the App and keep running App process in background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you mean by `minimizing that app` that the application goes to the background (is not the active application but it is still in the list of running applications). In case that is what you mean, please notice that this is the normal behavior in Android and many Mobile OS.

Terminating (exiting if you prefer) the application is not under the control of the application developer. It is completely managed by the OS (Android in this case). So, what you have is the normal behavior for apps under Mobile OS.

Instead of terminating the application as you would do under old OS (Linux, Windows and alike), you have to manage the lifecycle of the application: `pause`, `resume`, ...

Answer (score 0):

Install plugin https://github.com/ZhichengChen/cordova-plugin-android-home.
Implement 2 handlers for plugins.