# Cordova phonegap android application does not exit

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-plugins

I am New in phonegap cordova development.i make an demo apllication with help of google in cordova.here i take a button named exitapp and called function `navigator.app.exitApp()` function.here it is working fine but if I add some methods in mainActivity,java file then `navigator.app.exitApp()` function is not working.
I used

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

in html page.

my activity code is.

```
 package com.example.hello;
 import com.acl.paychamp.util.DecryptData;
 import com.example.hello.R;

 public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity implements  
  CordovaInterface
 {
CordovaWebView cwv;
private final ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
private CordovaPlugin activityResultCallback;
public static final String PASSKEY = "s407iejl";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.init();
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    cwv = (CordovaWebView) findViewById(R.id.view);     
    cwv.loadUrl(this.launchUrl);
 }


 @Override
public void startActivityForResult(CordovaPlugin command, Intent intent, int requestCode) {
    this.activityResultCallback = command;

    // Start activity
    super.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
}

@Override
public void setActivityResultCallback(CordovaPlugin plugin) {
    this.activityResultCallback = plugin;
}

@Override
public Activity getActivity() {
    return this;
}

@Override
public Object onMessage(String id, Object data) {
    try {
        URI uri = new URI(data.toString());
        if (uri.toString().contains("http://abcd.com/pr?
     param=")) {
            String encryptedText = uri.getQuery().split("=")[1];
            JSONObject jObj = DecryptData.getDecryptedJson(encryptedText,
       PASSKEY);
            Log.i("CordovaApp", jObj.get("msg").toString());
            Log.i("CordovaApp", jObj.get("trxid").toString());
            cwv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/status.htm?
       resparam="+encryptedText);

        }
    } catch (Exception use) {
    }
    return null;
   }

  @Override
    public ExecutorService getThreadPool() {
    return threadPool;

  }

 @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int 
  resultCode, final Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    CordovaPlugin callback = this.activityResultCallback;
    if (callback != null) {
        callback.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    }
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

> In case you mean by minimizing that app that the application goes to the background (is not the active application but it is still in the list of running applications). In case that is what you mean, please notice that this is the normal behavior in Android and many Mobile OS.
>
> Terminating (exiting if you prefer) the application is not under the control of the application developer. It is completely managed by the OS (Android in this case). So, what you have is the normal behavior for apps under Mobile OS.

SOURCE : [navigator.app.exitapp() not working in android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24756007/navigator-app-exitapp-not-working-in-android-device)